# Passing a function as prop with event and other arguments to a child component

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have fairly completed nav bar that need to be more complicated. I have a couple of links that are only available to users with certain permissions. If they don't have those permissions, then a modal is triggered letting them know they need to upgrade.

Part of the navigation is in a parent component, more of it is in a child component. In the parent component, I have a function that checks if they have the correct permissions, if they do it follows the link, if they don't it opens a modal.

```
const openModalOrFollowLink = (link, title, hasPermissions) => (e) => {
  e.preventDefault();

  if (hasPermissions) {
    // Here I'm setting some state based on what the title argument is
    // setSomeState(title)
    setModalVisible(true);
  } else {
    history.push(target);
  }
};
```

In the same component I have an onClick that calls this function:

```
onClick={(e) => openModalOrFollowLink(link, label, displayUpgradeMessages)(e)}
```

I'm passing this component to a child component like so:

```
openModalOrFollowLink={openModalOrFollowLink(
  link,
  label,
  hasPermissions
)}
```

In the child component I'm using this function that was passed as a prop like so:

```
onClick={(e) => openModalOrFollowLink(link, title, hasPermissions)(e)}
```

But in the function I'm getting an error because it's not getting the event:

> Uncaught TypeError: e.preventDefault is not a function

How can i get the event from the child to the parent so that I prevent the link from being followed automatically.

Comment: could you compose a codesandbox with an example? it's a bit hard to assemble the whole picture from these bits and pieces. From the first glance it seems you are passing  a second level function to `openModalOrFollowLink` prop - i.e. in the child's onClick the called `openModalOrFollowLink` is in fact `(e) => { ...}`, not `(a,b,c) => (e) => {...}`

Comment: Just by curiosity. Did you try with `(e)(link, title, hasPermissions)`?

Comment: @YegorBelov I still need to pass a,b,c as arguments though. I'll try to get a codesandbox going

Comment: @Alvin Interestingly the modal will open that way but it fails and says that openModalOrFollowLink is not a function. The antd Link component doesn't seem like it :/

Comment: @bonum_cete maybe you're intending to pass `openModalOrFollowLink={openModalOrFollowLink}` in the prop? then the child would actually pass all the params (at least from what I see here)

Comment: @bonum_cete `openModalOrFollowLink={ () => openModalOrFollowLink...` could solve that?

Comment: Got it working thanks to both of you. Just stupid oversights on my part. I'll update the post in a sec. Thanks again!

Comment: Could someone post the answer that way it can be accepted and show this question as solved?

Answer (score 0):

This is what ended up working for me

```
const Parent = () => {

  const openModalOrFollowLink = (link, title, hasPermissions) => (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();

    if (hasPermissions) {
      // Here I'm setting some state based on what the title argument is
      // setSomeState(title)
      setModalVisible(true);
    } else {
      history.push(target);
    }
  };

  ...
  return(
    <Child 
       openModalOrFollowLink={(e) =>
          openModalOrFollowLink(
            link,
            title,
            hasPermissions
          )(e)
        } />
  
}

const Child = (openModalOrFollowLink) => {
  return (
    <Link onClick={openModalOrFollowLink}> 
  )
}
```